# Unable to set up gitlab ci for golang

Tags: go, gitlab-ci

Below is the `before_script` for my gitlab golang ci project:

```
before_script:
  - git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir ~/.ssh
  - ssh-keyscan -t rsa devsb01 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  - git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com/<gitlabusername>/projectName.git
  - mkdir -p /go/src/gitlab.com/projectName /go/src/_/builds
  - cp -r $CI_PROJECT_DIR /go/src/gitlab.com/projectName
  - ls $CI_PROJECT_DIR
  - echo $PWD && ls
  - make dep
```

here the Makefile for dep target is as below:

```
dep:
    cd src;go get -v -d ./...;
```

but the ci recognizes the import incorrectly as below and fails:

[image]

[image]

The issue is that go get somehow is trying to clone the projectname/src.git which doesnt exist.

[image]

moving the fileUploader and the test to the src directory solves the issue but moving them to a new controller directory within the src directory fails

Comment: Why don't you use Go modules?

Comment: Yes, i am using go modules

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: If you are using go modules, then you should _not_ be running `go get ./...`

Answer (score 3):

try removing this

`git config --global url."git@gitlab.com:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"`

and all things related to the SSH keys

and add this line

- `echo -e "machine gitlab.com\nlogin gitlab-ci-token\npassword ${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc`

the `.netrc` will allow you the access to the private repo, for gitlab CI you do not need to handle ssh keys.

Comment: Thank you! I spent the past hour with a colleague with one Go project's inability to pull in a library from another where both were stored in subgroups. We kept getting "remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it. fatal: repository 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/group/subgroup.git/' not found"


Nothing we tried could convince the runner to look for `/group/subgroup/project.git`, which exists, instead of `/group/subgroup.git`, which doesn't. Replacing `insteadOf` with the `.netrc` line per your answer solved the problem!